# Cannot write from websocket server to browser app

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, websocket, serial-port

I believe this is a simple question:  I have a websocket server (index.js) that opens a serial port when the browser (index.html) is loaded.  I have a scale connected via USB (COM3).  From the browser I want to send commands to the scale and receive data back to the browser.  My node version is v7.7.4 and npm version is 4.1.2.  I have also NPM installed serialport and ws.

index.js

```
    var SerialPort = require('serialport');// include the library
    //var SerialPort = serialport.SerialPort; // make a local instance of it
    var WebSocketServer = require('ws').Server;
    var SERVER_PORT = 8080;               // port number for the webSocket         server
    var wss = new WebSocketServer({port: SERVER_PORT}); // the webSocket server
    var connections = new Array;          // list of connections to the server

    wss.on('connection', handleConnection);
      // get port name from the command line:
       portName = process.argv[2];

    var myPort = new SerialPort(portName, {
       baudRate: 9600,
       // look for return and newline at the end of each data packet:
       parser: SerialPort.parsers.readline("\n")
     });

    myPort.on('open', showPortOpen);
    myPort.on('data', sendSerialData);
    myPort.on('close', showPortClose);
    myPort.on('error', showError);

    // This function broadcasts messages to all webSocket clients
    function broadcast(data) {
     for (myConnection in connections) {   // iterate over the array of connections
      connections[myConnection].send(data); // send the data to each connection
     }
    }

    function sendToSerial(data) {

     myPort.write(" From: index.js:sendToSerial "+data);
     console.log("sendToSerial (index.js): " + data);
     // if there are webSocket connections, send the serial data
       // to all of them:
       if (connections.length > 0) {
         broadcast(data);
       }}

    function handleConnection(client) {

     console.log("New Connection"); // you have a new client
     connections.push(client); // add this client to the connections array

     client.on('message', sendToSerial); // when a client sends a message,

     client.on('close', function() { // when a client closes its connection
         console.log("connection closed"); // print it out
         var position = connections.indexOf(client); // get the client's position in the array
         connections.splice(position, 1); // and delete it from the array
     });
    }


    function showPortOpen() {
       console.log(portName+' port open. Data rate: ' + myPort.options.baudRate);
    }

    function sendSerialData(data) {
     myPort.write(" From: index.js:sendSerialData "+data);
        myPort.write("sendSerialData "+data);
       console.log("sendSerialData "+data);
    }

    function showPortClose() {
       console.log('port closed.');
    }

    function showError(error) {
       console.log('Serial port error: ' + error);
    }
```

and index.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
     <head>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.4.8/p5.min.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.4.8/addons/p5.dom.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript">

     var text;     // variable for the text div you'll create
     var socket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080");

    function setup() {

     // The socket connection needs two event listeners:
       socket.onopen = openSocket;
       socket.onmessage = showData;

       // make a new div and position it at 10, 10:
       text = createDiv("xxSensor reading:");
       text.position(10,10);

       }

    function openSocket() {
        text.html("Socket open");
        socket.send("Hello websocket server - from index.html");
      }

    function showData(result) {
        // when the server returns, show the result in the div:
        text.html("Sensor reading: " + result.data);
        xPos = int(result.data);        // convert result to an integer
        text.position(xPos, 10);        // position the text
      }
```

I have tried SERVER_PORT = 8081 with the same results.

I am able to see info from index.html in the cmd "node index.js COM3" but the command myPort.write does not get to the index.html browser.

I get:

```
C:\Users\pmfoo\nodeSerialExample>node index.js COM3
COM3 port open. Data rate: 9600
New Connection
sendToSerial (index.js): Hello websocket server - from index.html
sendSerialData       277.5     g
sendSerialData
```

where `277.5    g` is the output from the scale on COM3.

and in the browser:

```
Sensor reading: Hello websocket server - from index.html
```

I followed Tom Igoe's tutorial https://itp.nyu.edu/physcomp/labs/labs-serial-communication/lab-serial-communication-with-node-js/ with only partial results.  I cannot write from index.js to index.html nor can I send a command via index.js to the scale.  This scale command ("ON" or "OFF" or "PSN") is seen by index.js.  Can anyone help me solve these 2 communication problems?

Comment: It looks like you've mixed up `sendSerialData` and `sendToSerial` (which is easy to do given the confusing names). Rename one to `sendDataFromSerialToSockets` and the other to `sendDataFromSocketToSerial` and think again about what should go in each. Hint: you probably shouldn't be writing back to the serial port what you just read.

Comment: I changed those function names per your suggestion to make them more clear.  And those myPort.write stmts are intended for the browser.  Do I need a jQuery in index.html to be on the "lookout" for a feed from the socket?  And a sendScaleOutput process to get it there?